# How to show the map coordinates in the image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gis

I have generated an image after some processing in Matlab.  I have used the following code to read it.

```
[a b c]=geotiffread('sample.tiff');
```

I have used `imagesc` command to display the output image. I want to show rows and columns in terms of lat/long. How should I do it in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what is the **Question**

But if you want to set limits of x and y axis in map, use this simple codes.

```
xlim([lowerlimit upperlimit]);
ylim([lowerlimit upperlimit]);
```